# Cache file download in packer

Tags: packer

Packer automatically caches the OS ISOs when building. Is there any way to utilize this mechanism (or something similar) to provision files inside the VM so it doesn't redownload them every time?

Answer (score -1):

Use the sha256 of the url to download the iso as the base name of the iso file under packer cache directory. This avoids re-download.

See this link for more information: https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/1826